# Create PySimpleGUI list with a key

Tags: user-interface, pysimplegui

I wish to have a list of text items in a PySimpleGUI that I can update later. That is, I want to have a key for the list.  This might be vertical or horizontal, and I do not know how many items there will be.

I end up with different use cases, but the current one is to make a single line of text items with different colors.   Other times, I need to write and update a customized table, just different enough that the table widget does not work.

Conceptually, I want to do something like this:

layout = [ [sg.T('Titles and Things')], sg.ListThing(key='-data-', [[]]) ]

so that I can:

window['-data-'].update(values=[ [sg.T(v, color=c)] for (v,c) in my_data ])

Another, invalid syntax, way of saying what I want is to use `[key="-data-", sg.T('Item1'), sg.T('Item2')]`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can update individual layout elements but [you cannot dynamically change the layout itself](https://www.reddit.com/r/PySimpleGUI/comments/cdrjat/comment/etx1u2v/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

It is possible to create 2 or more elements, whereby only one of them is visible, and switch them later as needed. Or you can close and re-create the window with another layout. Or combine both approaches.

An example of switching layouts:

```py
def change_layout():
    left_col_1 = sg.Column([[sg.Text(f'Text {i}') for i in range(4)]], visible=True, key='col_1')
    left_col_2 = sg.Column([[sg.Text(f'Text {i}')] for i in range(6)], visible=False, key='col_2')
    visible_1 = True
    layout = [[sg.Column([[left_col_1, left_col_2]]), sg.Button('Change layout', key='change')]]
    window = sg.Window('window', layout=layout, finalize=True)

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        print(event)
        print(values)
        print(visible_1)
        if event in ('Exit', sg.WIN_CLOSED):
            break
        if event == 'change':
            window['col_1'].update(visible=not visible_1)
            window['col_2'].update(visible=visible_1)
            visible_1 = not visible_1
```

Please notice that the alternative layouts for the left part (`left_col_1`, `left_col_2`) need to be enclosed in a container (column, frame) to keep their position in the window in the moment they are invisible.

Comment: You can "add to a layout" by calling Window.extend_layout(container, rows).  Visibility as you've pointed out is another fine way to go!